# ERROR: attempt to redefine parameter "postgis.backend"

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I just install "SFCGAL". When I use "ST_3DIntersection", It get below error:

> ERROR: attempt to redefine parameter "postgis.backend" SQL state:
>   XX000

How can I fix?

I already saw http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html, but I do not know how should I do.

Comment: I also alter my database backend with follow code, but I get this error, yet.
ALTER DATABASE mygisdb SET postgis.backend = sfcgal;

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/132567/12379). It wastes everyone's time duplicating follow-up questions and replies.

Answer (score 0):

SFCGAL require to at least CGAL (Geospatial Data Abstraction Library) 4.1 and I already dose not install that. It has provided on : http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadSource